# Problems installing DEbian 8.2 (Jessie) on msi computer (during network install)

Tags: debian-installer

I want to install debian 8.2 (Jessie) on my msi GT70 2PE Dominator pro computer (which at the moment is running linux mint). I downloaded and burnt the debian 8.2 (amd64) install dvd-1.  It starts out OK, but when coming to installing the network drivers, there are problems. Some necessary drivers is not found on the dvd, and the following message is printed:

"Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a usb stick or a floppy.  The missing firmware files are:  iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode, iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode.
If you have such removable media now, insert it now, and continue"

I do have such files, which I found within the file firmware-iwlwifi_0.43_all.deb, which I downloaded, and the two cited files extracted from that deb file unto an usb harddisk. That harddisk was inserted, and I asked the installer to continue. It does not ask for which unit to use, so presumably it scans all the removable storage devices it can find.  BUT IT DOES NOT FIND THESE TWO FILES. Why???

So I had to abort the installation. What should I do? Shoukd I continue the installation, without configuring the network? Can I then configure the network afterwords?  By the way, if just continuing, trying to autodetect network hardware, the error message I get is:
"Network autoconfiguration failed. Your network is probably not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively ... "

Any ideas?

This have been marked by somebody as "possibly a duplicate", but is not. This question is about a problem during install, no resolved. The new question is about a problem after the install apparently finnished with success, but the installed os do not function properly.

Comment: Try "Expert Install" mode and configure the debconf priority to its lowest setting: this will ask you a ton of questions during the installation process. If I remember correctly, one of those questions should be where you would like to read additional installation files/drivers from.

Comment: copy the deb files to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` to get over the no network problem (this short-cuts the download part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by reading some of the posts/answers linked at in the "related" column at the right.  I had copied the files to an usb harddisk with ntfs filesysten. That was not searched. When I copied them on a usb stick with fat filesystem, they were found, and the install could progress.